# Using pre-installed library or packages with flask in python

Tags: python, virtualenv

I already have all the libraries required for development installed. But when I try to import them in flask virtual environment, it says "Module not found".
When I try to run python in command prompt without a virtual environment, it does import them without any error. So I have reached the conclusion that virtual environment needs all libraries installed again. I don't want to do that is there any other way?

Comment: Should be able to resolve this with PYTHONPATH, depends a little how your env is setup and such. But having 'duplicates' in your virtualenv is really no problem, in my experience the 'outside of env' modules are usually old and in the way.

Comment: I tried adding python path but idk why it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create your virtualenv with the [`--system-site-packages`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/#cmdoption-system-site-packages) flag, you can make use of globally installed packages. By default, you cannot.

Comment: Note - it's generally best *not* to do this, because that way you know that your `requirements.txt` is complete, including everything you need to run your application.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But somehow when I start jupyter notebook outside the env it gives this error: AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'. IDK if it is related to this or not.

Comment: Nevermind it was a problem with some library called typing. which is fixed by removing the library.