# Use Flask with other python libraries

Tags: python, apache, flask, virtualenv

I followed this nice tutorial: https://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2015/02/24/running-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2/ using a "Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type -" instance.

It works all nice until i attempt to use additional libraries like `jsonpickle`, `numpy`,....

I tried to follow this advice: [Using pre-installed library or packages with flask in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55829142/using-pre-installed-library-or-packages-with-flask-in-python) and create a virtualenvironment.

The error:

After installing numpy and adding `Import numpy` to flaskapp.py.

```
pip install numpy
sudo apachectl Restart
```

http://ec2-18-994-77-099.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/ doesn't work anymore.

Looking into `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

```
[Sat Nov 09 16:09:13.028377 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 9187:tid 140012532033280] [client 77.185.61.27:53340] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Nov 09 16:09:13.028396 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 9187:tid 140012532033280] [client 77.185.61.27:53340]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
[Sat Nov 09 16:09:13.028450 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 9187:tid 140012532033280] [client 77.185.61.27:53340]     from flaskapp import app as application
[Sat Nov 09 16:09:13.028461 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 9187:tid 140012532033280] [client 77.185.61.27:53340]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/flaskapp.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sat Nov 09 16:09:13.028489 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 9187:tid 140012532033280] [client 77.185.61.27:53340]     import numpy
[Sat Nov 09 16:09:13.028508 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 9187:tid 140012532033280] 

[client 77.185.61.27:53340] **ImportError: No module named numpy**
```

All steps I followed after spinning up the instance:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi

sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install flask

sudo apt install virtualenv
virtualenv --system-site-packages flaskyy

source flaskyy/bin/activate

mkdir ~/flaskapp
sudo ln -sT ~/flaskapp /var/www/html/flaskapp

cd ~/flaskapp
echo "Hello World" > index.html
```

(at which point navigating to http://ec2-18-994-77-099.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/flaskapp/ shows the html)

```
http://ec2-18-994-77-099.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com/flaskapp/

sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Comment: Your `pip` command is not the one attached to the Python version you use in your virtualenv.

Comment: Use `flaskyy/bin/pip install numpy` to install packages into your virtualenv.

Comment: We need to see your Apache mod_wsgi configuration if that didn't work (e.g. if you still had the virtualenv active), because it could well be that your WSGI setup isn't using the virtualenv.

Comment: See https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html for more info on mod_wsgi and virtualenv.